# Using Eclipse to work on a friend's Java project?

Tags: java, eclipse

Hey this may be a somewhat simple question, **but I'm new to Eclipse and was trying to get my friend's project to work on my own machine.**

He sent me his code, which I unzipped and extracted into my **home directory.** The structure of his project is such that:

- The src and bin directories are in a directory called **Circle,** which itself is listed under my home directory.
- Eclipse is installed under my home directory as well, but in a different folder called **eclipse.**
- So, my friend's src directory has two subdirectories, **circle** and **racket.** racket is another guy's project, but I imagine that both these directories will need to be used early on in my project
- Under the circle subdirectory are even more subdirectories, called **characters**, **experiments**, and **core**. Each of them only contain java files related to the project, but circle.java (the name of the project) is listed under the "core" subdirectory. However, "experiment.java" is listed under the "experiments" subdirectory, which I am not sure why it does not contain the main() method of the project.... (you want to *run* the *experiment*, right?) Instead, the main() method of the project is contained inside circle.java, which I am not sure why....

**Anyway, I was hoping someone could help me set this small project up (properly) using Eclipse.** I've never used Eclipse before, so some intuitive steps may need to be explained. Thank you so much, in advance for helping :)

****EDIT: Also, where should I put the **workspace**? Should it be defined in the home directory, or inside my friend's top Circle directory?

Comment: It took me forever to figure this out.  Only recently have I been able to import projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First place the .zip file anywhere; maybe a safe folder so it can stay there as a back-up.

Then these steps:

1. Click File -> Import
2. Select Existing Projects into Workspace
3. Select "Select archive file: "
4. Click browse
5. Point to the zip file
6. Check "Copy projects into workspace"
7. Select "Finish"

This should be sufficient to import the project with its structure to your Eclipse environment.

Don't forget that this is not the best practice to work on the same code. Try to set-up [SVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion) or other versioning systems.

Comment: I'm just wondering, do you know what the significance of an Eclipse workspace is? If you use Vim, for instance, I don't think they recommend/require that you create a workspace. I thought the 'Project' itself, should already be a workspace for the Project?

Comment: @John the workspace is the environment where you keep your configurations (related to editors, coding conventions, even color schemes) that you defined and all the projects you placed within. By using different workspaces you can have different configurations set-up for different types of projects. For example, back at school, I used to store each semester under different workspaces so that the one I worked with did not grow infinitely :)

Comment: @John see the edit on my post for comments about the function of an Eclipse workspace.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to open up Eclipse with whatever workspace you prefer and then import the project as an existing project.

You can do this by right-clicking in the package explorer view and selecting the import option. You then open the general tab, select existing project from file system. Simply navigate to the location of the project on your system and select it. The project wizard will take over from there. Navigate through the prompts and the project should be imported.

[image]

The package structure of Eclipse is a little complex. However, the nice thing is that you can simply import projects as explained above and not have to worry about all the gory details.

---

**Edit:** Where to put the workspace? This is pretty much your personal preference. I have a mac and Eclipse automatically sticks my workspaces in the Documents directory which I am perfectly happy with. I believe you can easily configure Eclipse to put these in different locations. The function of the *workspace* is to allow you to keep groups of project organized. For instance, if I am creating a system that has multiple project that all work in concert with on another, then I would like those to all be in a single workspace. My homework assignments for my computer science class can go in a different workspace and not clutter up my multi-project system.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to import the project, without worrying about each folder

[Example](http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/import_export/)